# Alternative values in a column to test with .isin() pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['apple and banana are sweet fruits','how fresh is the banana','cherry from japan'],columns=['fruits_names'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['apple','red'],['banana','yellow'],['cherry','black']],columns=['fruits','colors'])
```

Then the code:

```
colors =[]
for f in df1.fruits_names.str.split().apply(set):   #convert content in a set with splitted words

    color = [df2[df2['fruits'].isin(f)]['colors']]  #matching fruits in a list
    colors.append(color)
```

I can easily insert the color in df1

```
df1['color'] = colors

output:
                    fruits_names            color
0  apple and banana are sweet fruits  [[red, yellow]]
1            how fresh is the banana       [[yellow]]
2                  cherry from japan        [[black]]
```

The problem is if column 'fruits' has alternative values, like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[['green apple|opal apple'],'red'],[['banana|cavendish banana'],'yellow'],['cherry','black']],columns=['fruits','colors'])
```

How to keep this code working?

What I've tried for last was to create a new column with separated values for fruits:

```
df2['Types'] = cf['fruits'].str.split('|')
```

And .apply(tuple) here:

```
color = [df[df['Types'].apply(tuple).isin(f)]['colors']]
```

But it doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print(df1)

    fruits_names
0   green apple and banana are sweet fruits
1   how fresh is the banana
2   cherry and opal apple from japan
```

Use `split` and `df.explode()`

```
df2["fruits"] = df2["fruits"].apply(lambda x: x.split("|"))

df2 = df2.explode("fruits")

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   fruits              colors
0   green apple        red
0   opal apple         red
1   banana             yellow
1   cavendish banana   yellow
2   cherry             black
```

Convert it into `dict`

```
d = {i:j for i,j in zip(df2["fruits"].values, df2["colors"].values)}
```

Create a column based on a condition

```
df1["colors"] = [[v for k,v in d.items() if k in x] for x in df1["fruits_names"]]

print(df1)
```

Final Output:

```
    fruits_names                            colors
0   green apple and banana are sweet fruits [red, yellow]
1   how fresh is the banana                 [yellow]
2   cherry and opal apple from japan        [red, black]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['green apple and banana are sweet fruits','how fresh is the banana','cherry from japan'],columns=['fruits_names'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['green apple|opal apple','red'],['banana|cavendish banana','yellow'],['cherry','black']],columns=['fruits','colors'])
df2['sep_colors'] = np.where(df2['fruits'], (df2['fruits'].str.split(pat='|')), df2['fruits'])


dic = dict(zip(df2['colors'].tolist(),df2['sep_colors'].tolist()))

final = []
for row in range(len(df1.fruits_names)):
    list1 = []
    for key, value in dic.items():
        for item in value:
            if item in df1.iloc[row][0]:
                list1.append(key)
    final.append(list1)

df1['colors'] = final
```

Comment: Hi. Try this. You can further customize this using comprehensions in datastructures